# How to fix scons do not installed in Windows?

Tags: python, c++, pip, godot, scons

I was use godot for c++ and it native for c++ need to install scons. I was installed scons normally. But it caused a problem:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py:80: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
running install
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  self.initialize_options()
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py:66: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
        Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
        standards-based tools.

        See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  self.initialize_options()
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\test-easy-install-1112.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
I think this is error is in the file. So i use pip :"pip install scons". It run normally and i type "scons --version".But it say...
'scons' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I was search the internet and do like it. But nothing happend.
```

This is my scons file:

[image: The scons file:]

And this is the error problem:

[image: The problem]

And this too:

[image: The scons not be installed]

So i delete scons by "pip uninstall scons". I download again but the is no progress.
Can you help me?

Sery because i was new to stack overflow

Comment: Please don't screenshots of text. Paste the text into the description. It's easier to read and if we want to copy, paste, and fix your script, it's possible.

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: In your first screenshot, you're installing in a way that's not really supported anymore. The errors are actually coming from `setuptools`, which get invoked when you try `python setup.py install` - so let's not use that one.  Your second screenshot shows what looks like a successful install - there were no complaints - but `pip` helpfully warns you that the "executables" are not in the Windows search path. Have you tried the suggestion it gave you? That should clear up the problem of actually finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
python -nSCons
```

Also a really good way to install SCons (and/or any python package IMHO) is to install them in a virtualenv..
You can find instructions in our cookbook: https://scons-cookbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#setting-up-a-python-virtualenv-for-scons

```
C:\Users\user>cd Work
C:\Users\user\Work>py -m venv myvenv
C:\Users\user\Work>.\myvenv\Scripts\activate
(myvenv) C:\Users\user\Work>pip list --outdated
Package    Version Latest Type
---------- ------- ------ -----
pip        20.2.3  22.0.4 wheel
setuptools 49.2.1  62.1.0 wheel
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\user\Work\myvenv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(myvenv) C:\Users\user\Work\myvenv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools scons
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-22.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-62.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting scons
  Downloading SCons-4.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.2 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, scons
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-20.2.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.2.3
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 49.2.1
    Uninstalling setuptools-49.2.1:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-49.2.1
Successfully installed pip-22.0.4 scons-4.3.0 setuptools-62.1.0
(myvenv) C:\Users\user\Work>scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
        SCons: v4.3.0.559790274f66fa55251f5754de34820a29c7327a, Tue, 16 Nov 2021 19:09:21 +0000, by bdeegan on octodog
        SCons path: ['c:\\users\\user\\work\\myvenv\\lib\\site-packages\\SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2021 The SCons Foundation
(myvenv) C:\Users\user\Work> deactivate
C:\Users\user\Work>
```